# Why does cat <<< $VAR1 lose newlines?

Tags: linux, bash

Example 1: Print two lines from the shell

```
$ cat <<< $'Line 1\nLine 2'
Line 1
Line 2
```

Example 2: Does not print two lines, why?

```
$ VAR1=$'Line 1\nLine 2'
$ cat <<< $VAR1
Line 1 Line 2
```

Checking the value of `VAR1` to see if it is exactly what I set it to:

```
set | grep VAR1
```

Output:

```
VAR1=$'Line1\nLine2'
```

So, if `VAR1` is what I set it to, why does variable expansion produce a result different from the literal string - the `\n` is replaced with a space?

Comment: Use quotes `cat <<< "$VAR1"`

Comment: If you use `bash` 4.4 or later, the bug the causes `$VAR1` to be incorrectly subjected to word splitting has been fixed.

Comment: Generally the double-quoted version of a variable (`echo "$VAR1"`) preserves internal spacing of the value exactly as it is represented in the variable for newlines, tabs, multiple blanks and all.

Comment: In the unquoted `$VAR` the newline is taken as a whitespace delimiter, you get the same effect with `echo $VAR1`.  You need `<<< "$VAR1" cat` or `echo "$VAR1"`

Comment: @cdarke `cat <<< $VAR1` works when you aren't using a buggy version of `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the parameter expansions in a here string are not *supposed* to undergo word-splitting, that wasn't actually true until bash `4.4`. The newline in the expansion is treated as arbitrary whitespace, which the shell replaces with a single space before passing the result into `cat`'s standard input.

Quoting the expansion preserves the literal newline in earlier versions of `bash`:

```
bash-4.3$ VAR1=$'Line 1\nLine 2'
bash-4.3$ cat <<< $VAR1
Line 1 Line 2
bash-4.3$ cat <<< "$VAR1"
Line 1
Line 2
```

but the unquoted expansion works as intended in `bash` 4.4:

```
bash-4.4$ VAR1=$'Line 1\nLine 2'
bash-4.4$ cat <<< $VAR1
Line 1
Line 2
```