# Where did I make a mistake in this linux bash code?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

This code always returns the TRUE answer but the value of $myvar is "null"

```
if [ $myvar = "true" ]
then
cat << EOF > file1
blabla
EOF
echo $myvar
else
cat << EOF > file1
blublu
EOF
echo $myvar
fi
```

Where did I make a mistake ?
Many Thanks
Olive

Comment: What do you mean by _returns TRUE_? As it is posted, if `myvar` is empty, _blublu_ will be written to `file1`, and an empty line will be written to stdout.

Comment: even if an echo $myvar returns "null" file1 is written with blabla. I forgot to say it's a BASH script with  #!/bin/bash up the file

Comment: I just notice that you didn't use quotes. Therefore, if `myvar` would **really** be empty, you would get an error _bash: [: =: unary operator expected_ , and indeed the _then_ part would never be executed. I suggest that you do a `echo $BASH_VERSION; xxd <<<$myvar` right before the `if` statement, and tell us what output you get.

Comment: First: double-quote all variable references (i.e. `if [ "$myvar" = "true" ]` and `echo "$myvar"`) to avoid weird parsing. If it still doesn't work, put the command `set -x` before the problem section to get an execution trace and see what bash thinks is happening as it runs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : I prefer using `xxd` for inspecting the content of a variable over `echo`, because with _echo_, characters such as tab, spaces, carriage returns and similar ones sometimes get unnoticed.

Comment: @user1934428 `xxd` is good, but `<<<$myvar` is [buggy in bash versions below 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137589/why-does-cat-var1-lose-newlines/50137910#50137910); I'd use `printf %s "$myvar" | xxd` if you need to see *exactly* what's in a variable. But in this case, I think a `set -x` trace should be sufficient (and also gives a bigger picture of what's going on).

Comment: even with quotes, I have a "null" value for Myvar but the CAT function writes blabla...

Comment: @OliveDroid When you say "null", do you mean the letters "n", "u", and two "l"s, or do you mean the empty string? Also, did you try `set -x`, and if so what did it show? (Note: it'll be clearer to edit the `set -x` trace into the question in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), so it's readable, instead of adding it as a comment.)

Comment: ok Gordon, I put the "set-x" juste before the test. It reads : + '[' null=true ']' and next line "+ cat" next line + echo null  - null - + cat file1 - blabla  . In fact the variable comes with two possible values. "true" or "null" (strings)

Comment: @GordonDavisson : For older bash versions, `xxd <<<"$myvar"`  should work, because the quoted variant did not exhibit the bug you mentioned, and the quoted variant works in old and new bash. With `set -x`, I'm not sure that we can recognize easily all forms of white space UTF-8 shows us (think of carriage return, line feed, or the japanese half-width space). Since the OP incorrectly **believes** that his variable is empty, I guess that it is a white space issue, and seeing it in hex would be advisable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : What I like with your printf|xxd solution is that we don't see the terminating (and maybe confusing) `0a` which `xxd` would output for an empty variable when the command is used as suggested by me.

Comment: @OliveDroid : So you see that your variable is not empty. No surprise that it takes the `else` part. Voting to close the question because it is basically due to a typo (the variable contains a different value than expected).

Comment: @OliveDroid are there spaces around the `=` in the comparison? You need spaces around it, or it's parsed completely differently. See ["Why does adding spaces around bash comparison operator change the result?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365307/why-does-adding-spaces-around-bash-comparison-operator-change-the-result)

Comment: no there was no spaces. I tryed your xxx solution...and get many hexa characters.. Let's go and try the spaces. Can I post a screen to show you the colored code ? Because the test works in fact it says "null" or "true" as it should, but ALWAYS exectues the "true" command

Comment: Some news... If I put the value "null" to my variable, I have a Bash error : null - unknown command. if I put the value "true" to my variable, no error ! and the test works

Comment: @OliveDroid Did you remove the square brackets? Without them, it'll do something completely different (and completely inappropriate).

Comment: Yes no brackets ! Now the line reads : if "$myvar" = "null". I have in One case only an error message, but the test works

Comment: Use *exactly* this: `if [ "$myvar" = "true" ]` (or `if [ "$myvar" = "null" ]`) -- the brackets are required, and all of the spaces are required. If you leave any of those things out, it may not give an error, but it won't be doing the right thing. Also, I strongly recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), and fixing anything else it points out.

Comment: It Works perfectly ! many thanks to you all and specially Gordon. !

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple obvious errors in the command.

About your `if` statement:

First of all, square brackets `[]` are an alternative version of the `test` command. You want to use no brackets or parentheses `()`.

When writing oneliner you need to end each part of the command with a semicolon `;` or that your shell knows at which point you start a new command.

Also in nearly all cases you want to quote your variables.

This leaves you with the following:

```
if "$myvar" = "true"; then echo "is true"; echo "some other command";  else echo "is not true"; echo "another command; fi
```

I cannot say much about the rest of the command, as it is unclear what you are trying to do with all of these `EOF`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To be more precise, in a bash script, I want to fill a file depending of the result of a variable. If $myvar = "true" I write blabla. else I write "blublu" (not really that but you understand)

Comment: To compare strings, you *do* want `[ ]` (or the `test` command, or `[[ ]]` for bash's cleaned-up version). `if "$myvar" = "true";` will attempt to execute the value of `$myvar` as a command, and pass it the arguments "`=`" and "`true`".

Comment: ok you seem all to be right :-) It's with the brackets that is the problem. But when I remove them, I have a "unknown command : null=true" message